# How reliable [CALayer animationForKey:] is?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

I have a subclass of `CALayer` called `MyLayer`:

```
@interface MyLayer : CALayer
@property (nonatomic,readonly) BOOL busy;
-(void)performTask1;
-(void)performTask2;
-(void)performTask3;
@end
```

In `performTask*` functions I say:

```
-(void)performTask*
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [...];
    ...
    animation.removedOnCompletion = YES; // "YES" is default anyway
    ...
    [self addAnimation:animation
                forKey:TASK*_KEY];
}
```

The `busy` property is for the caller and implemented like this:

```
@dynamic busy;
-(BOOL)busy
{
        // i.e. for some specific ids
    return ([self animationForKey:TASK1_KEY] != nil ||
            [self animationForKey:TASK3_KEY] != nil);
}
```

What I see is that this approach is not reliable... I can see on the screen that animation **is** finished (nothing is moving, etc.), while `animationForKey:` does NOT return `nil`. The behavior is semi-random... Most of times it goes as expected. But sometimes it takes 1-2 seconds before I start getting `nil`-s.

This weird behavior **disappears**, if I set a delegate to animation `animation.delegate = self` **and implement** `animationDidStop:finished:`.

Someone experienced this as well?

Comment: are you checking it with animationForKey on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, everything in main gui thread...

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior and, as for you, adding a delegate and `animationDidStop:finished:` method gets the expected behavior to kick in. Very strange. Core Animation bug? Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring @dynamic causes CALayer to implement the accessor method for you (see [Properties on CALayer subclass aren't getting observed by CATransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936197/properties-on-calayer-subclass-arent-getting-observed-by-catransaction) and [CALayer and CAAnimation's dynamic resolution of unimplemented property accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516322/calayer-and-caanimations-dynamic-resolution-of-unimplemented-property-accessors)). So it's possible that you are just seeing confusion in which version of "busy" is getting called. Why did you declare "@dynamic" in the first place?

There could also be something funky happening with animationForKey, but I'd try removing the "@dynamic" first.