# Properties on CALayer subclass aren't getting observed by CATransaction

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, key-value-coding

I have a subclass of `CALayer` with a custom property, declared as such:

```
@interface MyLayer : CALayer
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *customValue;
@end
@implementation MyLayer
    @synthesize customValue = _customValue;
@end
```

I want to animate this property inside of an explicit `CATranasction`, so i set up a delegate with the `actionForLayer:forKey:` method implemented which returns an animation, however any changes to `someMyLayerInstance.customValue` inside of `[CATransaction begin] ... [CATransaction end]` do not result in `actionForLayer:forKey` getting called with a corresponding 'key' value.

However, nuking the property on `MyLayer` and making changes to `myLayerInstance` by calling `setValue:forKey:` **does** result in `actionForLayer:forKey:` getting called.

It appears that this is because `CALayer` does some mojo for key/value coding for undefined properties. How can I recreate this mojo so that I can declare properties on `MyLayer`, but still have them be observed by the animation delegate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most important thing is that you need to implement all `CALayer` accessors using `@dynamic`. Do not use `@synthesize` and do not implement the accessors directly. `CALayer` generates all its own property handlers (as you've indirectly discovered), and you need to let those be used.

You also need to let `CALayer` know that this property is display-impacting (which you may have already done given your other comments). If you haven't, you do this by implementing `+needsDisplayForKey:` and returning `YES` for your key.

Here's an example of a `CALayer` that animates a custom property (taken from Chapter 7 of [iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits](http://robnapier.net/book). The full [sample code](http://robnapier.net/bookcode) is available at the Wiley site.) This example implements `actionForKey:` in the layer, but you can still implement that part in the delegate if you prefer.

```
@implementation CircleLayer
@dynamic radius;

...

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
  if ([key isEqualToString:@"radius"]) {
    return YES;
  }
  return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (id < CAAction >)actionForKey:(NSString *)key {
  if ([self presentationLayer] != nil) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"radius"]) {
      CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation
                                animationWithKeyPath:@"radius"];
      anim.fromValue = [[self presentationLayer] 
                        valueForKey:@"radius"];
      return anim;
    }
  }

  return [super actionForKey:key];
}

@end
```